Trouble Plotting Seasonal Kendall Trend Test Results (EnvStats Package) in R
I am using the Kendall Seasonal Trend Test from the EnvStats package to assess water quality data.

I would like to plot trend lines using the intercept and Theil-Sen slope from the test result output but am having trouble getting a line to plot through my data. I'm unsure if this is a scaling issue with my graphs or something else?

I've also noticed the intercept values I get from the Seasonal Kendall Trend test are different from what I expected them to be and was wondering if someone might be able to explain why?


My understanding is that the intercept value for a Seasonal Kendall test is the median value of the intercepts produced by the individual Kendall trends run on each season. However, I’m getting values that don't seem to match. For example, if I run Kendall Trends on each individual season and calculate the median intercept, I get a value of 20.5. However, the Seasonal Kendall Trend result output is giving me a value of -44.4 for the intercept.
Below is an example of how I expected most of my graphs to look like:
seasonal_test_sal <- kendallSeasonalTrendTest(Salinity_ppth ~ month + year, data = df)
seasonal_test_sal
# Estimated Parameter(s):          tau       = -1.188119e-03
# slope     = -5.050505e-05
# intercept =  3.250258e+01

ggplot(df,aes(x= year, y = Salinity_ppth)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 3.250258e+01, slope = -5.050505e-05) +
  labs(x = "Year",
       y = "Salinity") +
  theme_minimal()

Salinity Plot
However, using the same code I am sometimes getting graphs that look like this for other water quality parameters:
seasonal_test_temp <- kendallSeasonalTrendTest(Water_Temp_deg_C ~ month + year, data = df)
seasonal_test_temp
#Estimated Parameter(s):          tau       =   0.10109619
#                                 slope     =   0.03838542
#                                 intercept = -44.36713333

ggplot(df,aes(x=year, y = Water_Temp_deg_C)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = -44.36713333, slope = 0.03838542) +
  labs(x = "Year",
       y = "Water Temperature (°C)") +
  theme_minimal()

#Note: this produces a line in the very upper left corner

Water Temperature
seasonal_test_TN <- kendallSeasonalTrendTest(TN_mgL ~ month + year, data = df)
seasonal_test_TN
# Estimated Parameter(s):          tau       = 0.0143334926
# slope     = 0.0001207307
# intercept = 0.3934360222

ggplot(df,aes(x=year, y = TN_mgL)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0.3934360222, slope = 0.0001207307) +
  labs(x = "Year",
       y = "Total Nitrogen") +
  theme_minimal()

#Note: the line for this trend seems too high?

Total Nitrogen
